# CSS bubble doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have some CSS:

```
.bubbledLeft,
.bubbledRight{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3px;
    max-width: 99%;
    clear: both;
        min-width: 99%;
}

.bubbledLeft{
    float: left;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 14px 10px 4px 15px; /*position within the border*/
}

.bubbledLeft:before{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    content: "";

    border-width: 8px 10px 8px 17px; 
    border-image: url("/assets/chat/speech_bubble_left_2.png") 8 10 8 17 stretch stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url("/assets/chat/speech_bubble_left_2.png") 8 10 8 17 stretch stretch;
    -moz-border-image: url("/assets/chat/speech_bubble_left_2.png") 8 10 8 17 stretch stretch;
    -o-border-image: url("/assets/chat/speech_bubble_left_2.png") 8 10 8 17 stretch stretch;
}

.bubbledRight{
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: right;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 4px 15px 4px 15px; /*position within the border*/  
}

.bubbledRight:before{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    content: "";

    border-width: 8px 17px 8px 10px; 
    border-image: url("/assets/chat/speech_bubble_right_2.png") 8 17 8 10 stretch stretch ;
    -webkit-border-image: url("/assets/chat/speech_bubble_right_2.png") 8 17 8 10 stretch stretch ;
    -moz-border-image: url("/assets/chat/speech_bubble_right_2.png") 8 17 8 10 stretch stretch ;
    -o-border-image: url("/assets/chat/speech_bubble_right_2.png") 8 17 8 10 stretch stretch ;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <textarea id="messageText" rows="3" style="width: 80%; resize: none;  height: 40px; border: 0px; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 999;" >Napisz wiadomość...</textarea>
    <button id="sendMsgBtn-ajax" class="sendMsgBtn">Wyślij</button>
    <div class="commentArea" id="commentArea">
        <% @msgs.each do |m| %>
            <% if (current_user.blank? == false && m.user.blank? == false && m.user.email == current_user.email) %>
                <div class="bubbledRight">
                    <%= m.body %>
                    <br />
                    <div class="date-right"><%= m.created_at.to_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") %></div>
                    <div class="nick-right"> ~<%= m.user.blank? == false ? m.user.email : "gość"  %></div>
                </div>
                <br />
            <% else %>
                <div class="bubbledLeft">
                    <%= m.body %>
                    <br />
                    <div class="date"><%= m.created_at.to_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") %></div>
                    <div class="nick"> ~<%= m.user.blank? == false ? m.user.email : "gość" %></div>
                </div>
                <br />
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly on Chrome, Opera and Safari but it doesn't on Firefox. Why ?

Screenshots (left chrome right firefox): http://ge.tt/7dGLW7U?c

Comment: With no HTML, CSS does nothing.

Comment: You also, to reiterate Kolink's comment, *need to show your HTML*, *not* the script that produces it.

Comment: First create static HTML/CSS page with your desired design on jsfiddle or dabblet, then it will be simpler to solve such cross-browser design problem. As far as I can see http://jsfiddle.net/cYsGE/ without border images works fine on FF. P.S. Division of development workflow into separate units of work (static HTML page with design concept, unobtrusive unit-tested script, and dynamic pages) is generally more efficient than mix everything together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox doesn't seem to like having `border-width` on its own without other border properties. Try adding this line before your `border-width` line:

```
border:solid transparent;
```

UPDATE:

The [latest CSS3 spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#the-border-image-slice) says that the border image should not be displayed in the middle of the box, so Firefox's implementation is correct. To show the border image in the whole box, add the `fill` value for the `border-image-slice` property, or use the `fill` keyword in the `border-image` shorthand. The following CSS should work for you:

```
-webkit-border-image: url("speech_bubble_left_2.png") 8 10 8 17 fill stretch;
-moz-border-image: url("speech_bubble_left_2.png") 8 10 8 17 fill stretch;
-o-border-image: url("speech_bubble_left_2.png") 8 10 8 17 stretch;
border-image: url("speech_bubble_left_2.png") 8 10 8 17 fill stretch;
```

Note that Opera doesn't support `fill` yet but it will work if you just use `stretch` on its own. Also, it's better to put the non-prefixed property last for browsers that support it, as this is the order that CSS rules are parsed.

Comment: Thank you very much, works better but not the best. Here is screenshot: http://ge.tt/5o6ULGU/v/0?c

Comment: I see. This can be fixed using the "fill" value - I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Works perfectly on each browser !